# What does shared memory do when they get 2 write request from 2 cores in RISC V multi core processor?

Tags: verilog, fpga, riscv, digital-logic, vlsi

I'm just doing a project "design a dual-core processor based on RISC-V ISA no pipeline, no private or share cache and 2 cores are shared a data memory". I have designed RISC V single core processor and it's worked. There are something i don't understand:

1)What does data memory do when it receive 2 write requests at the same address ?( i read book as the  image below =>So 2 cores have to race together to gain the access? is it safe for my design ( cause i think it's hard to verify when i pre-synthesized and simulate))Is there anyway better?
[computer architecture: a quantitative approach,6th - page 382](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn1Dg.png)

2)Most of multi-core processor references i referred are applied cache and use some protocols (MESI, MSI,MOSI...) to maintain the coherence, why the FSM of these protocols i only saw 1 event occur like R/W request from processor or bus at the same time , i didn't see how they execute 2 store instructions or load and store instructions ( same addr) simultaneously?

Sorry for too many questions, but I really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Alot of the material you're referencing is specifically about handling caches that are not shared by all cores (the book page you site, info about MESI, etc); handling shared access to a memory has different (And usually easier) challenges than handling caching. However, you specifically note that this project does not involve caching, so you should be careful conflating information about caching with information about memory in general.

1. Typically, write accesses to the same address will be serialized by the memory controller between the bus and the actual memory elements; so only one of the writes applies if two writes are issues to the memory to the same address. Depending on your memory, you might have to serialize all access anyway if it only has a single port as the memory itself can only have one access happen at a time. Generally, basic cores like the ones you appear to be implementing will stall until the memory access is complete, so if simultaneous accesses occur, one core will just stall longer while the first core's access is completed, then its own access is completed. In the case of say a dual core memory as is common in many FPGAs for onchip memories, you will need to look at the documentation posted by the manufacturer about multiple writes to the same address. Looking into Intel's (Altera's) documentation, you can get memory corruption if the same address is written to in the same cycle; so you would need to add an arbitrator to serialize accesses if two writes come to the same address in the same cycle with additional logic.
2. Generally, the examples you are seeing are simplified to make sure you understand the higherlevel technique used to maintain cache coherence. With any of these FSMs, how simultaneous access is handled is somewhat implementation dependent. Usually, some kind of arbitration ends up handling to access the bus so the write accesses end up being serialized, and so, for writes to the same address, one core will again "win" and have its write applied immediately after the other so memory will take on one of the values and not the other. If the implementation allows for multiple bus accesses in the same clock, additional logic would need to manage cases where multiple caches attempt to issue writes to the same address at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you give me a little bit detail about "additional logic" to handle multiple writes in case of the memory has multiple bus accesses. what is function of "additional logic"? does it use to decide which data of the core will be written into memory?

Comment: That "additional logic" would likely just serialize or maybe pick one of the access to perform. A simple implementation might compare the addresses going into the memory, and if they are equal, just eliminate one of them. So yes, it decides which to write to memory. Note that this is specifically for dual ported memories; memories with a single port would not need this logic as the accesses are never truly at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of arbitration.
There will be another device - a memory controller, or just arbiter - that will decide which cpu will get control over memory interface.

The arbiter will grant access to winning cpu, or assert wait request signal to cpu that had lost arbitration. The losing cpu will have to stall until the memory interface is available again -  the wait request signal is deasserted, or "grant access" signal asserted, depending on your memory bus architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm still not understand that in case of 2 writes at the same time and same address why we need to stall the losing cpu, because after executing 2 writes at the same time , the memory only receive 1 value , why we need to write the data from "winning" cpu  after that we overwrite that data into "losing" cpu data

Comment: @NguyễnPhanHoàngPhúc Generally the writes will be into different memory locations, so one cpu will have to wait anyway. Sure, you may build the arbiter in a way that won't stall the losing cpu when there's writes into the same location, just ignore its data. But that will be an optimization step, addition on top of existing stalling arbiter, with some hardware/complexity added.